# Regex for replacing a specific tag inside any html tag

Tags: php, regex

In one of my application i need to strip out or remove a particular tag inside all html tag attributes like :

```
 <div<del>class</del>=<del>"example"</del>>
```

I want to remove all these `<del>` tag which is generated from server side script. I am using the following `preg_replace`:

```
  preg_replace("/<.*?>/", "", $string);
```

But it is replacing all the tags and i only want to replace the tag within html tags. I dont want to remove all `<del>` tags. I only want to remove those `<del>` tags which are appearing inside html tags.

Answer (score 1):

Use the regex:

```
<[^<>]+>
```

Where `[^<>]+` is a negated class matching all characters except `<>`.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/pS6xO7)

However, if you have html tags without those tags inside, it will also replace the html tags.

If that's so, you might try this regex:

```
(?<==|")<[^<>]+>
```

EDIT: You should be more specific in your question if your problem is specific.

Just use the regex to replace:

```
<\/?del>
```

Comment: itz not working for me...its replacing all the tags and also all the attribute values but i only want to remove tag inside attribute value

Comment: I want to remove a specific '<del>' tag inside html tag attribute values

Comment: @VarinderKaur Could you post how it's not working in a sample code here: http://viper-7.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
preg_replace('/(?>(?><|\G(?<!^))[^<>]++\K|\G(?<!^))<[^>]++>/', '', '<div class=<some_tag>"example"</some_tag>>');
```

pattern details:

```
(?>            # non capturing group (atomic)
    (?>
        <|\G(?<!^)   # < or a contigous match
    )
    [^<>]++\K  # common content of the good tag until a bracket (\K reset the match)
  |            # OR
    \G(?<!^)   # a contiguous match not at the start of the string
)              # close the non capturing group
<[^>]++>       # the ugly tag to remove
```

Comment: Does not work of `<div class=<some_tag>"example"</some_tag>><div class=<tag>'quot="'</tag> id="divid"></div>`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte can you help me to strip out `<del>` tag from `<script>` and `<style>` tag blocks???

Answer (score 0):

You can do using this function

```
strip_tags('<div<del>class</del>=<del>"example"</del>>', '<del>');
```

if you use  **strip_tags** function you will get the following output

```
'<div class="example">'
```

Good Luck...