# Regex for replacing a specific tag inside html tags

Tags: regex

In one of my application i need to strip out or remove a particular tag inside all html tags like:

```
 Input: `<div<del>class</del>=<del>"example"</del>>`
 Output: `<div class="example">`
```

I want to remove all these `<del>` tag which is generated from server side script. I am using the following `preg_replace`:

```
  preg_replace("/<.*?>/", "", $string);
```

But it is replacing all the tags and i only want to replace the tag within html tags. I dont want to remove all `<del>` tags. I only want to remove those `<del>` tags which are appearing inside html tags.

Comment: What happened to your previous questions: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19150579/1578604) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19154041/1578604)?

Answer (score 0):

Use strip_tags

```
strip_tags($text, '<del>');
```

[manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Comment: As i have specified in the question that i dont want to remove all `<del>` tag ; i want to remove it only where yts included in html tags...

Answer (score 0):

Use str_replace

```
str_replace($input,"<del>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
preg_replace("/<tag>/", "", preg_replace("/<\/tag>/", "", $string););
```